# Excel vba error name in formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to pass one formula from vba excel to a cell i have this code

```
   atmFecha = "=IF(L" & tmLastRow & "=0," & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & ",'ws2'!$E$3)"    
    .Cells(tmLastRow, "H").Value = atmFecha
```

this instruction insert in the cell the correct formula but display **#NAME?** I have to press "F2" and then "Enter" to Excel recognize the formula and display the correct value.

I use the instructions formula and formulaR1C1 but the result is the same.

what can i do to recognize automaticly the correct value of the formula ?

Comment: `.Cells(tmLastRow, "H").Formula= atmFecha`

Comment: I am assuming that `atmFecha = "=IF(L" & tmLastRow & "=0," & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & ",'ws2'!$E$3)" `

Comment: I tried but not works continue displaying #NAME? in the cell, I edit my post to include this function and formulaR1C1. But thx for your comment.

Comment: do you have a sheet called `ws2` or is that a worksheet object in your code

Comment: Also can you paste the actual formula that you get when you press F2 and Enter

Comment: ws2 is the name of the sheet, and this is my formula `=IF(L78=0," ",'ws2'!$E$3)`

Comment: Hmmm that is strange. May I see the file?

Comment: Maybe try without the Chr(34)?  

`atmFecha = "=IF(L" & tmLastRow & "=0," & """" & ",'ws2'!$E$3)"`

Comment: Siddharth Rout I can't pass the original file but I created a new one and this have the same error. How I can do to pass the file?

Answer (score 1):

After your code, add this line:

```
Application.Calculate
```

It sounds like you are set to Manual Calculation, so that line will refresh everything. If you're setting a number of formulas, wait until they're all inserted, then execute that line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it fix but now is working, I was testing with the second file I made this is the code"

```
Sub btnCalculate()
    Dim atmFecha As String
    Dim tmLastRow As Integer

    With Worksheets("ws1")
        tmLastRow = 1
        atmFecha = "=IF(C1=0," & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & ",'ws2'!$A$1)"
       .Cells(tmLastRow, "A").Value = atmFecha
    End With
End Sub
```